# VBA Message Box does not execute when opeing a New Document in MS-Word 2016

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, msgbox

I have created a message box that automatically runs when a new document is opened based on a template:

```
' Display a pop-up message

Sub AutoNew()

MsgBox "UPDATE Page numbering if:" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "Additional pages are added" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "and/or" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & _
"Probation and/or Sex Offender case.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "REMINDER!"

MsgBox "UPDATE ""Schedule Of Payments"" if special payment terms are ordered.", vbOKOnly, "REMINDER!"

MsgBox "UPDATE page headers if additional pages are added.", vbOKOnly, "REMINDER!"

End Sub
```

We have several office personnel that use templates stored on our network.  The message boxes execute upon opening a new document, however, if that new document is still open and another new document is opened based on the same template is opened, the macro does not run.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Try AutoOpen instead of (or in addition to) AutoNew.